# Prove that $T$ is a homeomorphism of the circle if $|\epsilon|<1$

Tags: general-topology, circles

can someone give a help on this? Let $T:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be given by $T(\theta) = \theta + \omega + \epsilon \sin (\theta)$ where $\omega$ and $\epsilon$ are constants. Prove that $T$ is a homeomorphism of the circle if $|\epsilon|<1$.

Comment: $T$ does not even map onto $S^1$ for certain values of $\omega$.

Comment: @mathemagician99: It’s fine for real $\omega$. E.g., if $\epsilon=0$, $T$ is just a rotation by $\omega$.

Comment: I am assuming you take it mod $2\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem you might have is that $T$ is not one-to-one, since it is clearly continuous and periodic. But
$$
T'(\theta)=1+\epsilon\cos\theta
$$
which is strictly positive if $|\epsilon|<1$. So under this condition it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me a more detailed idea of how to prove the function is surjective?

Comment: Well, it is increasing and, as $\theta$ takes values from $0$ to $2\pi$, $T$ takes values from $\omega$ to $\omega+2\pi$, which, modulo $2\pi$, is the whole interval $[0,2\pi]$. All the values in between are achieved by the intermediate value theorem.