# Showing that a function is a homeomorphism of the circle

Tags: analysis, continuity, dynamical-systems

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $S:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ where is is given as
> $$S(\theta) = \theta + \omega + \epsilon \sin(\theta)$$
> and $\omega$ and $\epsilon$ are constants. Prove that $S$ is a homeomorphism of the circle if $|\epsilon|<1$.

I have that $S$ is a homeomorphism, but I used the Taylor expansion of $\sin$. I have no ideas about how to show bijectivity or that $S^{-1}$ is continuous because I'm having trouble inverting $\sin$. Maybe this can be done by more general arguments using Implicit Function Theorem. But this is the only half-thought I have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $T$ is a homeomorphism of the circle if $|\epsilon|<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687277/question-about-homeomorphism)

Comment: Ya its the same question, maybe it contains some hints, I'll read it. But at first glance, I need more detail to convince myself.

Comment: Note that as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $S$ is strictly increasing since it is differentiable and $S' >0$ everywhere (since $|\epsilon|>0$).

Comment: This equation is also known as the Kepler equation between the mean and eccentric anomaly of a planetary orbit. It is well known that no symbolic inverse exists, there are approximation and non-trivial series expansions. So yes, applying the inverse function theorem is appropriate here. Or just use the elementary theorems for scalar functions involving monotony.